# Failed joining ejabberd open room

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I sent my join request to an open room MUC like below:

```
<presence from="myJid@chatserver.com" to="roomname@conference.chatserver.com" id="17cb115c-2a7a-4aa6-8498-458a14c13f4d">
    <nick xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/nick">MyNickname</nick>
</presence>
```

But I keep getting error replies like below:

```
<presence xml:lang='fr' to='myJid@chatserver.com/resource' from='roomname@conference.chatserver.com' type='error' id='eff492ab-a438-4780-848b-bd98fed42294'>
<nick xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'>MyNickname</nick>
<x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
<x xmlns='vcard-temp:x:update'>
    <photo/>
</x>
<error type='modify'>
    <jid-malformed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    <text xml:lang='fr' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Le pseudonyme ne peut être laissé vide</text>
    <text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Nickname can&apos;t be empty</text>
</error>
```

The error said as if I didn't supply my Nickname, but I did. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you choose a nickname according to [XEP-0045](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#example-18).

The correct presence should be:

```xml
<presence
   from="myJid@chatserver.com/YOURCLIENTRESSOURCE"
   to="roomname@conference.chatserver.com/YOURNICKNAME">
    <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

The "from" attribute should include a resource, identifying your XMPP client.
The "to" attribute should be the room JID, with your desired nickname as a resource.

Note that for various reasons, the room might give you another nickname, see for instance https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#example-22